# reading an array of images in c++ (using opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv, stl

I want to read an array of images in c++ and I wrote this sample code:

```
std::vector<Mat> ReadInputImages()
{
    Mat tmp1=imread("C:/tmp/im1.jpg");
    Mat tmp2=imread("C:/tmp/im2.jpg");
    Mat tmp3=imread("C:/tmp/im3.jpg");
    Mat tmp4=imread("C:/tmp/im4.jpg");
    std::vector<Mat> images;
    images={tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4};
    return images;
}
```

But it doesn't work and I am getting compiler error on

```
   images={tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4};
```

What is the best way to return an array of images from a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++11 initialitzation syntax would be

```
std::vector<Mat> images={tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4};
```

or

```
std::vector<Mat> images{tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4};
```

But you do not need to declare a temporary vector, you can return one directly:

```
std::vector<Mat> ReadInputImages()
{
  return std::vector<Mat>{imread("C:/tmp/im1.jpg"),
                          imread("C:/tmp/im2.jpg"),
                          imread("C:/tmp/im3.jpg"),
                          imread("C:/tmp/im4.jpg")};
}
```

If you do not have C++11 support, you can simply push elements back into an existing vector,

```
std::vector<Mat> ReadInputImages()
{
    std::vector<Mat> images;
    images.push_back(imread("C:/tmp/im1.jpg"));
    images.push_back(imread("C:/tmp/im2.jpg"));
    images.push_back(imread("C:/tmp/im3.jpg"));
    images.push_back(imread("C:/tmp/im4.jpg"));
    return images;
}
```

Comment: Does visual studio 2012 support c++11?

Comment: @mans my understanding is that it supports [a large subset of it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). Unfortunately, according to that page, initializer lists isn't part of it.

Comment: Thanks. Which page do you referring?

Comment: @mans click on "a large subset of it" in my previous comment.